# Is it a bad idea to use ReportViewer control in MVC 5.2 (.NET 4.5) application

Tags: partial-views, reportviewer, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Since ReportViewer must be used with ASPX and that there is a lot of differences between WebForms and MVC, should I still go for a way to include ReportViewer control in my MVC application (as a partial view), or it is better to search for some other option? If it is not god idea to use ReportViewer in MVC, what other options do I have?

Comment: Have you tried a simple iframe directly to the report on the report server?  Add these to the report url `&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rs:Command=Render`

Comment: @freedomn-m No, I need local reports, because data source is custom

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `ReportViewer` requires `viewState` and that's not in MVC.

As you notice you will need to go through some hacks to make it work, if you google more you might find some libraries/github repos that will make that process easy.

Your best bet is to build it from scratch and get away from `webform` technologies but that's not also that easy, I know telerik built such things but it's not free although really worth it.

You just have to see what is the better option for you. This was an advantage of webform, just drag and drop the control and voila, but in MVC it takes more work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried par open solutions but those are not complete and are working in simplified cases. Most probably I will end up with exporting report to pdf, for example and showing that pdf, I don't see better solution at the moment. P.S. I did not saw that Telerik offers RDLC report viewer for MVC

Comment: Yes, Teleric offers report viewer, but this report viewer can't use old RDLC reports, it has it's own design patterns. I wanted to reuse RDLC reports because we have designed a lots of them and I wanted to avoid redesigning of everything, especially because these reports are also living and supported in old desktop apps